# On iOS device UIViewController returns System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException instead of actual View

Tags: ios, xamarin

I'm upgrading an existing game to work with iOS 9.2. I'm using Xamarin Studio v5.10.1 (build 6) and Xamarin iOS v9.4.0.0 (I'm current on the Stable and Beta channels).

I've got this piece of code in my UIViewController contructor.

```
public MainViewController() : base
{
    mainView = (MainView)this.View;
    mainView.mvc = this;

    InitializeDate();
    InitializeGame();

    GameLoop();
}
```

On the simulator running iOS 9.2 everything works correctly–this.View returns an instance of MainView which is stored in the instance variable mainView.

On the device, an iPhone 5S running iOS 9.2, this.View throws a System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException (the inner exception is a System.NullReferenceException).

On versions of iOS prior to 7.0 this code ran on the device without throwing the exception.

Moving the code above into ViewDidLoad or ViewWillAppear did not help on the device–the exception is still thrown.

I can post the stack trace if anyone thinks it will be helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In the ViewController's constructor, the View has not necessarily been created yet.  Try putting it in ViewDidAppear instead

Comment: @Jason - Moving the code above into ViewDidLoad or ViewWillAppear did not help on the device–the exception is still thrown. Do you have any idea why this might be happening on the device and not the simulator?